# missing right parenthesis when creating a view with an order by

Tags: sql, oracle

why this keep ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
CREATE VIEW LAPORAN_POSTINGANBULANAN (BULAN_TAHUN,JUMLAH POSTING) 
AS
SELECT TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') AS "BULAN_TAHUN", 
       COUNT(*) AS "JUMLAHPOSTING"
FROM POST (
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') ASC);
```

Comment: try to remove par here: `FROM POST 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') ASC;`

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the `group by` and `order by` part. The are completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the code, with a derived table you don't have to re-write the `TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM')` part several times:

```
CREATE VIEW LAPORAN_POSTINGANBULANAN (BULAN_TAHUN, JUMLAH_POSTING) AS
    SELECT "BULAN_TAHUN", COUNT(*) AS "JUMLAHPOSTING"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') AS "BULAN_TAHUN"
        FROM POST
    ) DT
    GROUP BY "BULAN_TAHUN"
    ORDER BY "BULAN_TAHUN" ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for paranthesis to wrap the group by as it is syntactically wrong.
Try removing it as below it should work

```
CREATE VIEW LAPORAN_POSTINGANBULANAN (
    BULAN_TAHUN
    ,JUMLAH POSTING
    )
AS
SELECT TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') AS "BULAN_TAHUN"
    ,COUNT(*) AS "JUMLAHPOSTING"
FROM POST
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') 
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The view is without parameters or output specification. Therefore I would write is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW LAPORAN_POSTINGANBULANAN AS
  SELECT TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') AS "BULAN_TAHUN", 
         COUNT(*) AS "JUMLAHPOSTING"
  FROM POST 
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM')
  ORDER BY TO_CHAR(POST.TANGGAL_POSTING, 'YYYY-MM') ASC;
```